# How to get information about a kubernetes installation?

Tags: kubernetes

Say you have a kubernetes installation, but you have no information about the time and the method the K8s cluster was installed.
I am talking about the K8s infrastructure itself and not K8s applications running on the cluster.

How would you find that?

I am looking for something like this:

```
kubectl/kubeadm(or some other command) cluster info
```

and for responses like these:
(*method/date/nodes*)

- `kubeadm-manually 2020-10-10T12:06:43 3nodes`
- `RKE 2020-10-10T12:06:43 3nodes`
- `EKS 2020-10-10T12:06:43 3nodes`

Currently what I am doing is looking for traces on the filesystem and on kubernetes resources (whether method specific pods,namespaces,labels..etc are exists)

Answer (score 2):

### kubectl cluster-info

There is a command [kubectl cluster-info](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#interacting-with-nodes-and-cluster), but it shows only endpoint information about the master and services in the cluster.

Example from docker desktop.

```
kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

Example from gke

```
kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://xx.xxx.xxx.xx
GLBCDefaultBackend is running at https://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/default-http-backend:http/proxy
KubeDNS is running at https://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
Metrics-server is running at https://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:metrics-server:/proxy
```

---

### Number of nodes

If you wan't to check how many nodes are in your cluster you can use [kubectl get nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#viewing-finding-resources).

Example from docker on desktop.

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME             STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
docker-desktop   Ready    master   5d22h   v1.19.3
```

Example from gke

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME                                       STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
gke-cluster-4-default-pool-ae8cecd9-m6br   Ready    <none>   2d16h   v1.16.13-gke.401
gke-cluster-4-default-pool-ae8cecd9-n9nz   Ready    <none>   2d16h   v1.16.13-gke.401
gke-cluster-4-default-pool-ae8cecd9-tb9f   Ready    <none>   2d16h   v1.16.13-gke.401
```

If you wan't to get just the number of running nodes .

```
kubectl get nodes --no-headers | grep -v Running | wc -l
```

---

### Method

You could try to do that with few commands from this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242062/how-to-get-kubernetes-cluster-name-from-k8s-api) question.

For example:

- `kubectl config current-context`
- `kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.clusters[].name}'`
- `kubectl -n kube-system get configmap kubeadm-config -o yaml <--- kubeadm only`

---

### Date

Couldn't find any informations about that, as a workaround you can try to check nodes/kube api-server creationTimestamp, but if there was any restart on the node/kube api-server pod then the data will get updated.

Example from docker desktop.

```
kubectl get node docker-desktop -o jsonpath='{.metadata.creationTimestamp}'
2020-11-13T10:09:10Z

kubectl get pods -n kube-system kube-apiserver-docker-desktop -o jsonpath='{.metadata.creationTimestamp}' 
2020-11-13T10:10:12Z
```